# Curve of equal alternate angle differences on a rotating line

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

Several points  on a smooth  curve are connected a fixed point O on the x-axis and the line segments make angles a,b,c .. to the x-axis.

If tangents of the curve at these points make angles $ A,B,C .. $ to these rays and the angular differences  $A-a, B-b, C-c, .. $ are equal .. then find the equation of  curve .

[image]

Comment: Is it supposed to satisfy the conditions for all points on the curve, or just those three points?

Comment: Curve through points such that differences $ D-d, E-e,... $ are all constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the given figure you are speaking about a positive oriented curve (i.e. the origin lies in the left-hand region with respect to the direction along the curve) and the internal angle (i.e. the angle between the directed tangent and the direction **to** the origin).

I will assume that in line with the clarification in the comments all points of the curve should satisfy the above condition (if it should have been valid only for a finite set of specified points the number of smooth curves satisfying the conditions would be infinite).

The equation to find the curve reads:
$$
\frac1r\frac{dr}{d\phi}=-\cot(\phi+\phi_0),\tag1
$$
where $\phi_0$ is the constant (in your notation $\phi_0=A-a$)

The equation $(1)$ can be easily integrated giving rise to the solution:
$$
r=\frac{d}{\sin(\phi+\phi_0)}\quad (-\phi_0<\phi<\pi-\phi_0),\tag2 
$$
which is the equation of a straight line, with $d$ being the distance from the origin to the line and $\phi_0$ being the supplementary of the line inclination angle.